# creating a multi-level role based access in firestore security rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to implement a multi-level based role in firestore with security rules.

I have a two role based which is `admin` and `superadmin` and an admin can only `read`
however a `superadmin` can do the CRUD operations. This is the structure of my rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isSuperAdmin() {
      return request.auth != null && resource.data.admin == 'SuperAdmin'
    }
    function isAdmin(){
        return request.auth != null && resource.data.admin == 'Admin'
    }

    match /admins/{admin} {
      allow read, write, delete, update, create: if isSuperAdmin()
      allow read: if isAdmin()

    }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow create, read, update, delete: if isSuperAdmin()
      allow read: if isAdmin()
    }

  }
}
```

and these are my fields from firestore and the error simulation for firestore security rules.

admin:
[image]

superadmin:
[image]

security rules:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you want, in your security rules, to check the user’s role which is stored in the document in the `admins` collection that has its ID corresponding to the user’s uid.

If this understanding is correct you should use the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) method as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) in the doc:

```
function isAdmin(){
    return request.auth != null && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/admins/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == 'Admin'
}
```

Comment: Hello. May I ask why do I get ``Function [get] called with malformed path: /databases/(default)/documents/admins/`` or do I have to check the path? thanks!

Comment: I've just tried it and it does work. You may update your answer with the exact code used to read the data and the new set of security rules.

Comment: Hey @flutternewbiee, did you have the opportunity to debug your code and try the proposed approach?

Comment: Hello, I am so sorry for not accepting it immediately as soon as it worked.. Yes it worked, thank you so much!